# Component not updating even though useState value has changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a dynamic dropdown using bootstrap. The items in this dropdown will change dependent on the value selected in the previous dropdown. The value in the previous dropdown changes successfully and the state also changes but {userName} does not re-render after each select.

```
const users = ... // API call from server 

const [userName, setUserName] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
   console.log(userName) // userName successfully changes at each select
}, [userName]);

function handleSelect(event) {
   setUserName(event.target.value)
}

return (
   ...
   <Form.Group> 
      <Form.Label>
         Select User
      </Form.Label>

      // This part works fine 
      <Form.Control 
          as="select" 
          onChange={handleSelect} 
          className="form-select"
      > 
           {users.map(names => {
               <option key={names.value} > {names.name} </option>
           }
     </Form.Control> 

    <Dropdown> 
       // userName doesnt change 
       <Dropdown.Item> {userName} </Dropdown.Item> 
    <Dropdown>
   ...
 )
```

Comment: I don't follow, if `userName` has updated in the `useEffect` when you log it, it's the same value used in the render return. In other words, it's the state value for *that* render cycle. Can you create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue that we can inspect and live debug in?

Comment: can you provide codesandbox for this ?

Comment: Why are you setting your initial state an Array? if it is only one userName

Answer (score 1):

I have used the same code which you have provided and it is working for me.

Maybe this snippet helps you.

```js
// Get a hook function

const { useState, useEffect, Fragment } = React;
const { Form, Dropdown, Row, Col, Container } = ReactBootstrap;

const Example = ({}) => {
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState([]);
    const users = [
        { name: "abc", value: "abc" },
        { name: "xyz", value: "xyz" }
    ];

    function handleSelect(event) {
        setUserName(event.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <Container>
            <Row>
                <Col sm={6}>
                    <Form.Label>Select User</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control as="select" onChange={handleSelect} className="form-select">
                        {users.map((val) => {
                            return <option key={val.value}> {val.name} </option>;
                        })}
                    </Form.Control>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
             <Form.Label>Selected Value:</Form.Label>
                <Dropdown>
                    <Dropdown.Item>{userName}</Dropdown.Item>
                </Dropdown>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(<Example title="Example using Hooks:" />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"
  crossorigin></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

Unlike the setState method found in class components, useState does not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread syntax:

```
        function handleSelect(event) {
           setUserName((prevValues) => return [...prevValues, event.target.value])
        }
```

Comment: I think the array as initial state is an error since the UI is rendering a `select` input and the change handler is only handling a single value. And the fact that the correct value is logged in the `useEffect` hook is a tip that the state is correctly updating as expected.